# Macro that exports sheets to new workbooks except a speciffic sheet

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, split, worksheet

So I have a macro that exports each sheet into a new workbook. Now my problem is that I don't want to export a specific sheetname/(s) ("Source" sheet lets say) and when I add the code "If xWs.name<>"Source" then and add the else and end if I still get the "if without block if etc" error. I tried a lot of ways but is not functioning.

Can someone help ?

```
    Sub SplitWorkbook()
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim FolderName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    DateString = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
    DateString2 = Format(Now, " - MMMM YYYY")
    FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & "Re'porting_" & DateString
    MkDir FolderName
    For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
    Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56:
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
    End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & 
    DateString2 & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Proper indentation (like in your `Select Case` statement) helps a lot with debugging - I reccomend following that in future - I can't see the `If` statement in question though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and added the desired `If...Then...Else` statement. I've also formatted it with indentation and spacing between key steps in the code which makes it easier to read and identify when the code is doing/evaluating something new.

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
DateString2 = Format(Now, " - MMMM YYYY")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & "Re'porting_" & DateString
MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    If Not xWs.Name = "Your Worksheet name to exclude" Then  'Change this string to suit your worksheets name
    xWs.Copy

        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            Select Case xWb.FileFormat
                Case 51:
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                Case 56:
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else:
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If

    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & DateString2 & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Else
        'Go to next worksheet
    End If
Next xWs

MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This compiled and ran fine for me (except it was in an unsaved new workbook so the filepath basically didn't exist  - so I commented out the `MkDir` and `...Save` satatements).

I've also used `If Not xWs = "..."` rather than `If xWs <> "..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Samuel Everson, I have added the lines as you sugeested and it works. I am posting here the working code + I have changed the topic name to be findable.

```
    Sub SplitWorkbook()
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim FolderName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    DateString = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
    DateString2 = Format(Now, " - MMMM YYYY")
    FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & "Reporting_" & DateString
    MkDir FolderName
    For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    If Not xWs.Name = "Comands" And Not xWs.Name = "Source" Then
        xWs.Copy
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            Select Case xWb.FileFormat
                Case 51:
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56:
                            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else:
                            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
        xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & DateString2 & FileExtStr
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Else
        'go to next worksheet
        End If
    Next xWs
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '
    Sheets("Comands").Activate
    End Sub
```

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue you should mark it as accepted that way the community can see what solved your problem - generally there is no need to post your own answer in the way you have, as the only extra information you've provided is *specific* to your own application and is unlikely to be useful or helpful to others with similar/the same problem. :)

Comment: Technically the code is very general and can be ajusted. Btw how do I mark the topic answered ?

Comment: Click the 'tick' symbol underneath the up/down vote buttons to the top-left of the answer.